# How to copy tables in mysql from one database to another that start with wp_?

Tags: mysql

```
USE wordpress1;
CREATE TABLE products LIKE wordpress.products;

INSERT INTO products  
    SELECT * FROM wordpress.products;
```

This code allows you to copy the table one at a time. And how to make it copy all tables starting with "wp_"?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that you can do this:

1. Use the mysqldump command. This will create a SQL script that you can then run on your destination database.
2. Use the MySQL Workbench. This is a GUI tool that will allow you to visually select the tables that you want to copy over.
3. Use a tool like phpMyAdmin. This will also allow you to visually select the tables that you want to copy